# Why is my image turning gray when I paste another image on it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images

I opened a `.jpg` file that only contains one channel, whenever I try to add another image to the file, the other image also turns gray.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 11):

I suspect your image mode is set to Grayscale. Change it to something else using the <kbd>Image → Mode</kbd> menu.

[image: Image Mode menu]

Comment: Just to add to this answer, you will have to re-add any new images you dragged into this document now. Anything dragged in while it was Grayscale will have lost their color information.

Answer (score 1):

Your mode is set to grayscale. Anything you put in there wil be gray. Change the mode to RGB.